# How do I find out the manufacturer of a phone that is lost?

Tags: lost-phone

How do I find out who the manufacturer is of a lost phone I have the serial number I also have the Sim number and I know that it is a safe link phone.

Comment: If you have the IMEI you can derive the manufacturer from the first few characters as it is a code for the vendor.

Comment: The SIM number identifies the sim card inside the phone.  The SIM card may hsve been plugged in after manufacture.